# Can't resolve teiid-parent maven heirarchy

Tags: maven, jboss, teiid

- What do repositories must I add need to enable consumption of teiid-admin via maven?
- Why does a released version of teiid depend on a pre-release ancestor pom (org.jboss.as:jboss-as-parent:pom:7.5.0.Final-redhat-15 pom file in the jboss **"Product EAP 6.4.0 Alpha"** repository)

I must be doing something wrong because I can't add Teiid admin to my project because the pom ancestry disappears into a non release repository.  Does this seem right?

**Error Seen**

`Could not find artifact org.jboss.as:jboss-as-parent:pom:7.5.0.Final-redhat-15 in org.reficio (http://repo.reficio.org/maven/)  @ org.jboss.teiid:teiid-parent:8.12.0.Alpha3-SNAPSHOT,...pom.xml, line 376, column 23 -> [Help 2]`

**Dependency Added**

`<dependency>
     <groupId>org.jboss.teiid</groupId>
     <artifactId>teiid-admin</artifactId>
     <version>8.11.0.Final</version>
     <!-- same basic thing happens with <version>8.11.2</version> -->
</dependency>`

- I can see [org.jboss.as:jboss-as-parent:pom:7.5.0.Final-redhat-15](https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/index.html#nexus-search;gav~org.jboss.as~jboss-as-parent~7.5.0.Final-redhat-*~~) pom file on the jboss "Product EAP 6.4.0 Alpha" repository
- I cannot find it in the release repository.
- When I attempt to list either of these as dependency or build the equivalent source for teiid admin tags I get a variation on that error.

Please let me know if you have any ideas because after hunting around the jboss nexus instance I'm more confused than when I started.

Thanks

Peter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Question and answers from Jboss Community](https://developer.jboss.org/message/938187#938187) provided the solution.  To use teiid via maven one must proxy or add all these repos to your settings file

```
      <id>jboss-public-repository-group</id>
      <name>JBoss Public Maven Repository Group</name>
      <url>http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/</url>

      <id>jboss-public-repository-group</id>
      <name>JBoss Public Maven Repository Group</name>
      <url>http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/</url>

      <id>jboss-developer-repository-group</id>
      <name>JBoss Developer Maven Repository Group</name>
      <url>http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/developer/</url>

      <id>jboss-techpreview</id>
      <name>JBoss Tech Preview</name>
      <url>https://maven.repository.redhat.com/techpreview/all/</url>
      <layout>default</layout>

      <id>jboss-earlyaccess</id>
      <name>JBoss Early Access</name>
      <url>https://maven.repository.redhat.com/earlyaccess/all/</url>
```

Comment: There is also a settings.xml file with the repo, you can use -s settings.xml with your maven execution